# Uncaught ReferenceError: Searchbar is not defined

Tags: reactjs

Sorry, i am new in React.
I have 2 components in my react application. Here is the parent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './Searchbar';

const App =() => {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
            <Searchbar></Searchbar>
            <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

}

export default App;
```

and here is the searchbar component:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

export default class Searchbar extends Component{

    render(){

       return  <div>Here is search bar</div>;
    }  
}
```

Unfortunately, when the page loads it complains with the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Searchbar is not defined
```

It seems that, it does not recognize the Searchbar component.
What is the problem?

Comment: You have to do `import Searchbar from './Searchbar'` because you need to import the default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is really simple. You are importing the searchbar wrongly in your file. You need to import it like `import Searchbar from './Searchbar';` , since you have exported it as default you also need to import it in default manner.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Searchbar from './Searchbar';

const App =() => {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
            <Searchbar></Searchbar>
            <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

}

export default App;
```